# Accessing local IP address via a hostname

Tags: networking, proxy, localhost

How can I access a local network IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.91) via a hostname from another machine in the same network (e.g. localhost)?

The reason I want to do this is because my local server running my development application can be accessed from other machines via the IP, however the web app is Dependant on the host name remaining consistent.

You can see where the problem arises when the server is told to fetch images and scripts that rely on the host being `localhost` and not `192.168.1.91`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use `localhost` only to refer the loopback address (127.0.0.1).

In your case best option would be to register the server in DNS (e.g. test-server.example.com).

If you don't have access to DNS you should be able to use `hosts` files instead. Just add the following line to your hosts file on all computers that need to access the server:

```
192.168.1.91 test-server.example.com
```

`hosts` file can be found in `/etc/hosts` in Linux and in `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Windows.